Correct way to Middleware with NodeJS, ExpressJS, Tokens (Login & Dashboard)?
Hope your'll fine. We'll I have a problem using NodeJS, especifically with a Middleware, in my case it supposed to have a Dashboard with two cases:

If user try to go /dashboard without login -> send to /login
If user go to /dashboard with correct login -> show /dashboard

But I have error with the correct way,
const verificarToken = (req, res, next) => {
  // Excluir recursos estáticos como favicon, imágenes, archivos JS, etc.
  if (req.path.match(/\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$/)) {
    return next();  // Continuar sin requerir token
  }

  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  console.log("Encabezado Authorization recibido:", authHeader);  // Depuración

  if (!authHeader) {
    console.log("No se proporcionó un token. Redirigiendo a /login.");
    return res.status(403).json({ mensaje: 'No se proporcionó un token' });
  }

  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];  // Extraer el token después de 'Bearer'
  jwt.verify(token, 'secreto_jwt', (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Token no válido. Redirigiendo a /login.");
      return res.status(401).json({ mensaje: 'Token no válido' });
    }
    req.usuario = decoded;
    next();  // Continuar si el token es válido
  });
};

verificarToken is my Middleware, and the section of login and dashboard:
// Ruta para el Login (GET)
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
});

// Ruta protegida para el Dashboard (GET)
app.get('/dashboard', verificarToken, (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/dashboard.html');
});

// Ruta de login (POST)
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { nombre_usuario, password } = req.body;

  // Buscar al usuario en la base de datos
  conexion.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario = ?', [nombre_usuario], (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ mensaje: 'Error en la consulta' });
    }
    if (results.length === 0) {
      return res.status(401).json({ mensaje: 'Usuario no encontrado' });
    }

    const usuario = results[0];

    // Comparar la contraseña ingresada con la almacenada en la base de datos
    bcrypt.compare(password, usuario.password, (err, esValido) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ mensaje: 'Error al comparar contraseñas' });
      }
      if (esValido) {
        // Generamos el token de seguridad
        const token = jwt.sign({ nombre_usuario: usuario.nombre_usuario, rol: usuario.rol }, 'secreto_jwt', { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.json({ mensaje: `Bienvenido ${usuario.nombre_usuario}`, token });  // Devolver el token al cliente
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ mensaje: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
      }
    });
  });
});

showing the way of security using Token, Bcrypt etc...
login.html script:
  <script>
// Lógica para manejar el login
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir que el formulario se recargue

  // Capturar los valores de los campos
  const nombre_usuario = document.getElementById('nombre_usuario').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  // Enviar la solicitud POST al servidor
  fetch('/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ nombre_usuario, password })
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Verificar si la respuesta fue exitosa (status 200-299)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Error en la solicitud de login');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', data);  // Mostrar la respuesta en la consola
    if (data.token) {
      // Guardar el token en localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      console.log('Token guardado en localStorage:', data.token);

      // Verificar acceso al dashboard con el token
      verificarAccesoDashboard(); 
    } else {
      // Mostrar un mensaje de error si las credenciales no son válidas
      document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = 'block';
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
    document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = 'block';
  });
});

// Función para verificar el acceso al dashboard usando el token
function verificarAccesoDashboard() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (!token) {
    console.log("No se encontró token. Redirigiendo a /login.");
    window.location.href = '/login';
    return;
  }

  // Hacer la solicitud GET a /dashboard con el token en el encabezado Authorization
  fetch('/dashboard', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'include'
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
      console.log("Token inválido o acceso denegado. Redirigiendo a /login.");
      window.location.href = '/login';
    } else {
      console.log("Token válido. Mostrando dashboard.");
      window.location.href = '/dashboard'; // Redirigir ahora al dashboard
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error en la solicitud al dashboard:', error);
    window.location.href = '/login';  // Redirigir al login si ocurre un error
  });
}

  </script>

in this scenario I delete every script on dashboard.html, what I was expecting is a successfull login, but after making the "fetch dashboard with GET method" the node server show
"Encabezado Authorization recibido: Bearer token"
and just after that shows
"Encabezado Authorization recibido: undefined"
"No se proporcionó un token. Redirigiendo a /login"
and is in this point that I need help, I understand that the first log of node server is with the Fetch Method GET to Dashboard, but the next one is the "window.location.href" that is not giving the header "Authorization ...".
So how can make a Middleware successfull or in other words how can I make the correct way?
Deleting script on Dashboard.html
Using FETCH METHOD in login.html before the redirect to /dashboard

what do you mean by I delete every script on dashboard.html? the issue is that window.location.href = '/dashboard' won't set an Authorization header - you should use cookies if you want to navigate using window.location.href

by the way, this took a long time to understand due to the non-English log messages
